# Nativescript vue webpack configaration missing

Tags: nativescript-vue, webpack.config.js

I;m beginner to nativescript-vue. When i initiate my project with following command tns run android  it will occur below error

**The webpack configuration file /home/camilus/laravel/vue-native/drawer/webpack.config.js does not exist. Ensure you have such file or set correct path in nsconfig.json**

So could you please solve this issue.